# httpd failed due to SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' on centos 6.7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, https

I am trying to update TLS1 to TLS1.1 or higher but after doing below changes, Getting error "SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1'"

My Apache and openssl version are :-

> httpd -v

**Server version: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 16 2012 21:11:37**

> openssl version -a

**OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Tue Sep 27 12:27:19 UTC 2016**

Centos-version (6.7)

> rpm --query centos-release

**centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64**

Did changes for ssl :-

> **SSLCipherSuite** ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
>
> **SSLProtocol** -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
>
> **SSLHonorCipherOrder** on

I am not sure what is missing here, can anybody help me here,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please upgrade your CentOS. It is too old.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Is it? The [CentOS 6.5 release notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.5) state that TLS 1.1 support was added. And the [OpenSSL changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x26) states that TLS 1.1 support was added in 1.0.1.